# Connect Intranet(OnPremise) SharePoint Server 2013 from Console C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, intranet

I have tried to implement on-premise SharePoint connecting from console as mentioned in following article,
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205515/first-time-connecting-to-sharepoint-server-2013-from-console/205529?newreg=95ed260c717c4d9fb5fe4856a2daf71a

But things is that when execute program it throws internal exception(Code : 500). Unable to connect server :-(

Please check below code and let me know where/what I did wrong.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://customersupport/"))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("connecting on-premise sharepoint....");

                clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"domain\username", "password");

                // Get the SharePoint web  
                Web web = clientContext.Web;

                // Load the Web properties  
                clientContext.Load(web);

                // Execute the query to the server.  
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("Conneciton done successfully");

            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                //throws internal exception
                Console.WriteLine(exe.Message);
            }
        }
```

below is full error message:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at ConnectSharepoint.SharePointOnPremise.Main(String[] args) in C:\Kishor\ac\2018\Test\ConnectSharepoint\SharePointOnPremise.cs:line 34
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the *full* exception, including the call stack. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()` or a simple `Console.WriteLine(exe)`. If you call the wrong URL though, you'll only get an error back. BTW you *don't* need to specify username/password if you want to connect with your current credentials. That means either don't set anything to the `.Credentials` property or set it to [CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: BTW instead of trying code at random, [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code). You need to pass the *SharePoint site URL* to the constructor. One SharePoint installation can have many web applications. Those applications in turn can have many independent sites.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added full exception message.

Comment: did you check the URL? Did you *remove* the credentials, so you can connect with your own credentials? Can you connect to that site in the first place?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I had check with **CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials                 ** and  **CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials** facing same issue still.

Comment: forget the code. Can you browse to the site? Is the URL correct? That's a server error. You can't fix it from the *client* side. It could be an actual problem with the installation or it could be because the ULR is wrong, or because you don't have permission to connect to *that* particular site. Or maybe the REST endpoint isn't active. You'll have to check SP's logs for errors. You should also check the actual response to the HTTP call - SharePoint uses a custom error page that contains a GUID that can be used to check the log.

Comment: You can use an HTTP debugging proxy like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check the actual HTTP call made to the site and the actual response. This will show you what the *actual* URL used by the Client API was. You can use that URL to check whether you can connect from the browser

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I can browse mentioned site.

Comment: And? What was the URL shown in Fiddler? What was the response? What did Sharepoint's log say? These aren't idle questions. You *can't* solve a server-side Sharepoint error  otherwise. `Yes, I can browse mentioned site.` doesn't mean you can call the REST endpoint or that it's even available

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will contact with our admin person about REST endpoint activation.

Answer (score 1):

Check the follows:

**1.Check all of your app pools, and check if the "SharePoint Web Services Root" stopped.**

[image]

**2.Check these SharePoint Services.**

[image]

**3.Check the IIS Admin Service.**

[image]